# How select the gender in registration form by selenium 2.0?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I want to create a bot, which will be registrate accounts in gmail.
I have problem with selecting the month of birth.
I'm programming on C# using Selenium 2.0.

Source code of this "complicated" part.

```
    <legend><strong id="BirthdayLabel">Birthday</strong></legend>
  <label id="month-label" class="month">
  <span aria-invalid="true" class=" form-error" id="BirthMonth"><div aria-activedescendant=":0" title="Birthday" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="listbox" class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select"><div aria-posinset="0" aria-setsize="12" role="option" id=":0" class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption">Month</div><div aria-hidden="true" class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown">&nbsp;</div></div><input id="HiddenBirthMonth" name="BirthMonth" type="hidden"></span>
  </label>
```

I do it like this:

```
var txtBirMon = Driver.FindElementById("month-label");
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
action.ClickAndHold(txtBirMon).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```

First I doing it another way:

```
txtBirMon.Click();
txtBirMon.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowUp);
txtBirMon.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```

But it's not focusing on txtBirMon and just scroll down the page...
But it doesn't work. What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because **you are not `perform`ing the actions**:

```
action.ClickAndHold(txtBirMon).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter).Perform();
```

Comment: I have another question: Can I send more than 1 "Send Keys"? e.g. firstly I click "Arrow Up", secondly -> enter?

Comment: @KirillKZ yes, sure, you can chain the actions as much as you want.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very grateful to you for your help.

Comment: If this answered your question, please make sure you accept it as the answer. Thanks!